# On Research Topic

Tags: physics, research-topic

I want to start my new research on those fields of physics which are remained as unsolved problems or remarkable suitable area specially in Quantum and Einstenian physics .
I really want to understand advantages of these fields which are remained unsolved for a long decades .
I failed to find out mostly relevant advances in physics . plese give me suggestions for this problem . I will be grateful for a good suggestion .

Answer (score 3):

How to pick a research topic is something you learn by doing a PhD, and coming up with the right question is probably one of the hardest bits of a research project. If you pick the wrong question to ask then it is not clear what your end goal is, if you pick the right question then the research can be like figuring out which of the tools you already know can be used to construct a solution. In some regard, asking for a good research project can be like asking for someone's research (as a vague analogy).

Problems that have remained unsolved for a long time are often quite difficult and I would guess progress is not made on them until either 1) a new tool is developed, or 2) the question is rephrased in a better way to make it more tractable. For those reasons they aren't the best place to start doing research until you have a deep understanding of the topic and related fields. Based on one of your other questions I know that you are currently in high school, so you would likely need to learn the field better before you can make progress in these problems. Instead you should look for an advisor if you want to do research, since its both important for learning to have someone who is skilled that can critique your work, and (ideally) they can direct you towards more approachable problems.

Comment: I did not realize that he was a high-schooler :)